# python overlapping values from serial

Tags: php, python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I have my arduino connected to the pi via usb and it is sending readings from a DHT sensor using the simple program below (this bit works as expected in the arduino serial monitor):

```
int chk = DHT.read11(DHT_PIN);
Serial.println(DHT.temperature,1);
delay(2000);
```

I then have a python program which should get the data from the serial port:

```
import serial
conn = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
temp = conn.readline()

print temp
```

This script is then called in php using `$temp = shell_exec('python temp.py 2>&1');` which works fine but the values I get from the serial are wrong.

The expected output should be something like `23.0` but when I refresh the page (or even run the python script in terminal) I get values like `2323.0`, `23.023.0`, `22..0` and `2`. These change all the time and very rarely come out in the desired format.

It seems as if the data from serial is overlapping, even though the `Serial.println()` function puts it on a new line. If someone could tell me how to correct this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I've looked around on a few sites and found this page http://www.elinux.org/Serial_port_programming quite helpful. I looked at some of the code and noticed that with my original code within `serial.Serial(...)` I just entered the baud rate after a comma without specifying `baudrate=9600`.

```
import serial
port = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',baudrate=9600,timeout=3.0)
temp = port.readline()

print data
```

This code appears to have fixed the problem! Here's a screenshot of it in action http://gyazo.com/22e7801fd0d7cdf2873e627bb8b88fdc.

Answer (score 0):

try `print repr(temp)`  ... or even `print temp.strip()+"  .  "`

I very stronly suspect when you read you get

```
"23.0\r"
```

`\r` returns your cursor to the start of the line

if you do `print "23.0\rB"` you will see `"B3.0"`

(ie i think you are seeing the overlap only because you are printing it...)

Comment: Using the `rep(temp)` method just gives `'222.0\r\n'` and the problem of values changing persists. The `temp.strip()+"  .  "` is just putting an extra decimal point and the end of the number.